# Not able to call api from client side script

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I wrote the following code for calling the API from client script.

**Cshtml**

```
<button class="btn btn-link btn-sm js-toggleFollowing" data-user-id="@gig.ArtistId">Follow</button>
```

**API Call:**

```
$(".js-toggleFollowing").click(function (e)
{
    var button = (e.target);

    $.post("/api/followings", { followeeId: button.attr("data-user-id") })
    .done(function ()
    {
        button.text("Following");
    })
    .fail(function ()
    {
        alert("Something failed");
    })
});
```

**API Controller Method**

```
// Code for api call

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Follow(FollowingDto dto)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    if (_context.Followings.Any(f => f.FolloweeId == userId && f.FolloweeId == dto.FolloweeId.ToString()))
        return BadRequest("The Following alreday exists.");

    var following = new Following
    {
        FollowerId = dto.FolloweeId.ToString(),
        FolloweeId = userId
    };

    _context.Followings.Add(following);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok();
}
```

DTO Class:

```
public class FollowingDto
{
    public int FolloweeId { get; set; }
}
```

API call is working with postman without converting the parameter to DTO. But it is not working when i use the dto as a parameter. dto class is also copied.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you enable camel case? Where is your route mapping? /api/followings?

Comment: what mean by no able to call? any error? can u do a log inside the button and inside the ajax too? n also open the developer console check the network tab whether click it did fire?

Comment: Normally, the post's parameters will be sent through the request's body so you should add [FromBody] to make sure that it will be mapped correctly
`public IHttpActionResult Follow([FromBody] FollowingDto dto)`

Comment: You're missing a `$` here `var button = (e.target);` before the open bracket.

Comment: @Hooman Thanks for the reply. Now call worked but getting followeeId as null in the controller class. How followeeId will get converted to FollowingDto. What else am i missing in code?

Comment: your button needs to be a jQuery object, before you can use attr() function. try this: var button = $(e.target). Thats what Musa has told you as well.

Comment: @Hooman Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks all for the valuable comments.